# Jeditable not working with dynamically added element (ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, jeditable

I am using `jeditable` to edit `answers` of `question`
I have implemented the entire logic successfully expect for new answer which are added to the dom via ajax.
Initially newly added dom were not editable, but after following some solution it start working partially.

Below are my code snippets

```
$('.answer-section').delegate('.answer-descp', 'edit', function(){
    $(this).editable('/answer/update', {
        type    : 'textarea',
        event   : 'edit',
      }
    });
});
```

The link which fire `edit` event to edit the content (It is also part of dynamically added dom)

```
$('.answer-section').on('click', '.editans', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(e);
    $(this).parent().parent().prev().trigger('edit');
});
```

`answer-section` is class of `div` which contain all answer and the dynamically added new doms are added within it.
`answer-descp` is class of `div` which contains the text that have to be edited by `jeditable`.
When we post new answer (via ajax) new dom is added with `answer-descp` div containing answer text and a new link with class `editans` which when clicked edit this newly added answer

My problem is that I have to click the edit link 2 times in order to make it editable. I tried many variation but didn't succeeded.
Thanks in advance

Comment: are there other `.answer-section`?
Check if the `e.preventDefault(e);` isn't blocking the `$(this).parent().parent().prev().trigger('edit');` why you use it?

Comment: So that I can edit answers only through clicking via edit link.

Comment: you could simulate the `<a href></a>` tag with CSS so you can avoid it's default behavior... check [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/), it's also usefull in this cases...

Comment: Problem is why the event is triggered on second click ?

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but I had the same problem, and get annoyed with these unanswered questions.
The answer is so clear in the end, but maybe this saves some odd minutes banging your head in.

**The first click adds the editable event to the element the second triggers it.**

There is no click event needed to add editable, and it ads its own to trigger it.

For me it worked to call `.editable()` directly after adding it to a modal
i.e.

```
$('#someID').contextmenu(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.someClass').modal('<span class="editable">'+someVal+'</span>'));
    $('.editable').editable('some/URL/'); 
}
```

For ajax, this should probably be done in the `success` part.